# Query with variable assignment not returning results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query that uses variables, however I want to be able to run this and have results shown from the Select statement. All I am getting is a Message "Commands completed Successfully" instead. I have tried tinkering with the advanced Query Options with checking the 'SET NOTEXEC' option but this did not yield results.

```
DECLARE @ErrorCount AS INTEGER;
DECLARE @MinErrorDateTime AS DATETIME;
    
SELECT @ErrorCount = COUNT(IBTRANSACTIONID)
      ,@MinErrorDateTime = MIN(ERRORTIMESTAMP)
FROM PSIBERR 
WHERE MESSAGE_NBR <> 0
  AND ERRORTIMESTAMP >= DATEADD(mi,-62,GETDATE())
```

Comment: You need to do an additional select statement `Select @ErrorCount as ErrorCount, @MinErrorDateTime as MinErrorDateTime` Or if this is a stored proc, then set those variables as output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

You need to do an additional select statement. After your query add this.  Also, if this were a stored procedure you could add the variables as `Output` variables to return the values.

```
Select @ErrorCount as ErrorCount, @MinErrorDateTime as MinErrorDateTime
```